# Best place to watch for solidity contract events in react

Tags: reactjs, events, solidity

Which lifecycle method is best suited for watching events emitted from contract?  I am thinking componentsdidmount.  Just wanted to get some inputs from experienced developers.  Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by contract? @Bill

Comment: Hi anshui thank for the reply. I mean solidity.

Answer (score 1):

componentDidMount() is the best place to listen to solidity events